# Retrieve data in IMS from J2EE application

Tags: jakarta-ee, mainframe, ims-db

Currently, i have a J2EE application that retrieves data from IMS database through MQ. We would like to fetch data directly instead - without using MQ. Is there any option? Any connectors that we could deploy in our server (WAS 6) that would help us communicate to IMS and retrieve data from it? Any links in this regard would also be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You may already have found this, but IBM provides a [JCA adapter for IMS](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/ims/ims/components/tm-resource-adapter.html)

Comment: Yes, some time with google helped me reach there. Trying to explore how to use that. Thanks.

Comment: JCA is a mystery to me. Never been anywhere near that API, it looks unpleasant.

Answer (score 0):

I have just answered a similar question here:
[Connect to IMS with Open Database from .Net application or using JDBC ..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12823903/connect-to-ims-with-open-database-from-net-application-or-using-jdbc)

Basically, you should look into whether the [IMS Open Database](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg247856.html) could meet your requirements.